# Can Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core execute packages

Tags: oracle, .net-core

Is there a method in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core that enables you to execute PL/SQL packages? We used Devart and they have a method called OraclePackage but we want to go with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core nuget dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the Oracle package executed with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core dependency.

Here is an example of how I did it:

```
         OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("User Id=UserID;Password=Password;Data Source=localhost;");
         OracleCommand cmd= new OracleCommand();

         cmd.CommandText = "PACKAGENAME.FUNCTIONNAME";

         cmd.Connection = connection;
         cmd.Connection.Open();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parameterName: "retVal", type: OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parameterName: "P_Param1", type: OracleDbType.Varchar2, obj: "SAMPLE1", direction: ParameterDirection.Input));

OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```